Python list insert(0,...) out of order
I am working with a Python list of dictionaries. I am trying to order the list by moving dictionary items to the top. However, the list.insert(0, dictItem) is not working as I expect each iteration to insert at the top of the list. (i.e., a push-down stack) But it puts the first iteration at index 0 and the next at index 1.
What am I missing?
theList = [{"V":"1"}, {"V":"2"}, {"V":"3"}, {"V":"4"}, {"V":"5"}]

i = -1
for vMove in {"4", "5"}:
    for listDict in theList:
        i += 1
        vName = listDict.get("V")
        if vName == vMove:
            break
    theList.insert(0, theList.pop(i))
    i = -1

print(theList)

Expected Result:
[{'V': '5'}, {'V': '4'}, {'V': '1'}, {'V': '2'}, {'V': '3'}]

Actual Result:
[{'V': '4'}, {'V': '5'}, {'V': '1'}, {'V': '2'}, {'V': '3'}]

Yes, I know I can reorder vMove, but I am curious why it works this way.

You are using a set in the for loop. Sets are unordered so vMove might not be what you expect. Try for vMove in ("4", "5"):

@001 is correct. If you run the code you have provided multiple times, you should see that the result will vary between the expected result and the variant where the 4 and 5 dicts are flipped.

@AlexDuchnowski Sets don't randomly change when iterated.  But sets are unordered.  If print(vMove) is added OP will see that it prints 5, 4 every time.  A different Python implementation may be different, but consistent.

@MarkTolonen If print(vMove) is added between the two for lines, sometimes 4 is printed first and sometimes 5 is printed first (at least with Python 3.10). So it is not consistent. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your point. As a minimal example, the following varies from execution to execution:
for x in {"4", "5"}:print(x)

@Alex Items are inserted into a set based on an implementation-defined hash.  The hash doesn't vary from run to run so it shouldn't change.  It doesn't in Python 3.12.

@Alex Ah, it does seem to be randomized from run-to-run.  A particular instance of the Python interpreter remains consistent, but if I restart the interpreter, it does vary.  The implementation must vary the hash at startup...looking for some documentation...

@Alex Found it.  Python 3.2.3 added hash seed randomization.  The hash is salted with a random value on startup.  "Although they remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not predictable between repeated invocations of Python."

Why are you using a set in the first place?

FWIW, Pylint says "Use a sequence type when iterating over values" because they're more efficient than sets

As mentioned by @001, sets are unordered.  OP is using a set {'4', '5'} instead of an ordered list or tuple.  As of CPython 3.2.3, Python hash randomization is on by default so the order of values in a set changes at every invocation of the Python interpreter, but remains consistent in a particular invocation.
>>> print({'4', '5'})  # set (unordered, varies by invocation of Python)
{'5', '4'}
>>> print(('4', '5'))  # tuple (consistent order).
('4', '5')

Using a tuple (and enumerate instead of awkward i implementation):
theList = [{'V': '1'}, {'V': '2'}, {'V': '3'}, {'V': '4'}, {'V': '5'}]

for vMove in ('4', '5'):  # tuple
    for i, listDict in enumerate(theList):
        vName = listDict.get('V')
        if vName == vMove:
            break
    theList.insert(0, theList.pop(i))

print(theList)

Output:
[{'V': '5'}, {'V': '4'}, {'V': '1'}, {'V': '2'}, {'V': '3'}]

One could also look up the index directly:
theList = [{'V': '1'}, {'V': '2'}, {'V': '3'}, {'V': '4'}, {'V': '5'}]

for vMove in ('4', '5'):
    theList.insert(0, theList.pop(theList.index({'V': vMove})))

print(theList)

